# Visual Studio Solution with Several Projects Using Different Version Control Systems (Subversion and TFS)

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tfs, projects-and-solutions

If I have a solution in VS (any version really, but I'm currently on 2013) which has multiple projects, can each of those projects use a separate version control system with VS integration (i.e. a plugin of some kind)? Will VS 'play nice'?

The solution itself can only be in one version control system.

For example

```
My Solution // .sln file is in SVN
  |
  |- Project 1 
  |        // This uses SVN and VisualSVN plugin (or another Subversion plugin)
  |- Project 2 
  |        // This uses TFS and Team Explorer plugin
```

Will Visual Studio work with both version control plugins seamlessly? Or can I expect weird crossover effects with files being added to both systems?

Comment: which version control is the solution in? :-) you would probably have to do a lot of work outside of the ide to map your files and download them, before opening the solution. if you click on the solution and click get latest what would it do?

Comment: The solution is in SVN - I'll add that to the question. Your comment is basically the kind of thing I'm worried would happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have a different Version Control configured for each project in a Solution. Version control is configured at the solution level and set on/off at the project level.

I would be more interested in **why** you believe that this behaviour is required? As that would be off topic you should mail me directly.

Comment: I don't believe the behaviour is required, I just wonder if it's possible. The reason why is because we have 2 teams at my workplace who are using different version control systems. Usually we never have any crossover in our code bases but it's reached a point where one team needs to use another's code in the same solution.

Comment: Never ever use another code I your solution. There is nothing more detrimental to quality than source dependencies / pinning / sharing / externals or whatever your source control system callers them. One reason why the TFS team continue to refuse to implement anything like that. You should package the dependency as a NuGet package and share in that form.

Comment: I agree completely. After considering our options we decided to do a NuGet package. The original question was more of a theoretical proposal.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in the sense that dependencies between projects cannot be tracked. As an additional side effect one change that changes three projects can no longer be done as a single checkin and the atomic nature of the checkin is lost as it needs to be done by multiple source control systems.

**in short select the same source control system for all related projects**